# Using 'Case' when two columns are equal

Tags: vba, excel, loops, case

I am trying to create a case within VBA where a ":)" will be in column AL when Columns AJ & AK are the same value:

```
Sub ColumnAL()

Dim LockDays, StartCounter, LastRow, Equal, BuySideLockDays, PreviousCell


Worksheets("Table").Activate
LastRow = LastRowNum(Sheets("Table"))
Cells(1, 36).Value = "BuySideLockDays"
Cells(1, 37).Value = "LockDays"
Cells(1, 38).Value = "Equal"

For StartCounter = 2 To LastRow
LockDays = Cells(StartCounter, 37).Value

Select Case LockDays
    Case Is = BuySideLockDays
        Equal = ":)"

   Case Else
        Equal = "!!!"

End Select
Cells(StartCounter, 38).Value = Equal


Next StartCounter

End Sub
```

I am also using a PublicFunction to set my LastRow Number which seems to be working:

```
Public Function LastRowNum(Sheet As Worksheet) As Long
If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Sheet.Cells) <> 0 Then
    LastRowNum = Sheet.Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                    LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                    SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
Else
    LastRowNum = 1
End If
End Function
```

Excel Sheet is current returning only "!!!"

Comment: In your code `BuySideLockDays` is never assigned a value.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub ColumnAL()

    Dim StartCounter, LastRow
    Dim ws As Worksheet, rw as Range    

    Set ws = Worksheets("Table")

    ws.Activate

    LastRow = LastRowNum(ws)

    ws.Cells(1, 36).Value = "BuySideLockDays"
    ws.Cells(1, 37).Value = "LockDays"
    ws.Cells(1, 38).Value = "Equal"

    For StartCounter = 2 To LastRow

        Set rw = ws.Rows(StartCounter)
        rw.Cells(38).Value = _
           IIf(rw.Cells(36).Value = rw.Cells(37).Value, ":)", "!!!")

    Next StartCounter

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You code works fine, except that you forgot one statement:

```
BuySideLockDays = Cells(StartCounter, 36).Value
```

put it right before the select statement. (tested)

Comment: @TimWilliams Sorry didnt see your answer before posting mine. Should I delete?

Comment: If the OP is happy with the rest of their code then they can just add your line...

Comment: Usually this is what i try to do, help fix the given code with minimum change. But I do appreciate other's efforts (such as yours) to suggest full clean solutions :)